# Getting unique document counts for top hits array aggregation, sum_other_doc_count

Tags: elasticsearch, unique, aggregation

I have a large amount of documents (millions) that have arrays of keyword values:

Mapping:

```
{
    "my_index": {
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "keywords": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example documents:

```
{
  "id": "abc",
  "keywords": ["cat", "dog", "person"]
}
{
  "id": "def",
  "keywords": ["tree", "person"]
}
{
  "id": "ghi",
  "keywords": ["person", "human"]
}
...
```

Let's say I am getting the top 3 keyword buckets and have the rest show up in “other” like so:

```
/GET /my_index/_search
{
    "size": 0,
    "track_total_hits": true,
    "aggs": {
        "keyword_buckets": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "keywords.keyword",
                "size": 3
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are 2,232,121 documents but I am getting the buckets like this:

```
{
    "took": 256,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 2232121,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "keyword_buckets": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 6250132,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "person",
                    "doc_count": 326552
                },
                {
                    "key": "human",
                    "doc_count": 326529
                },
                {
                    "key": "photograph",
                    "doc_count": 222190
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting 6,250,132 documents in the “other” bucket. My expectation is that the sum of the top 3 and the “other” would be 2,232,121. In SQL terms it would be getting `DISTINCT` document counts for all the buckets.

What is the query I need to do to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch doesn't give you the exact doc_count. Doc counts are always approximate. This is because the by design elasticsearch query looks at each shards top terms and combines them. You can read more about it [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-approximate-counts).

Comment: yeah i read that but it seems odd for it to be off by so much. we are talking 300%+ difference

Comment: especially noting the part that says `"doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0`

Comment: yes this is expected. Elasticsearch doesnt work like SQL. You can increase the accuracy using these methods described here https://qbox.io/blog/elasticsearch-aggregation-custom-analyzer

Comment: why is ES saying the error is 0 in every case, even if I set `show_term_doc_count_error` to true?